# Why can't I open a new window on my jquery ajax callback?

Tags: jquery, callback

to show my problem in a couple examples...

THIS WORKS

```
$.post("SomePage.aspx", { name : "value" },
      function (data) {
         alert(data);
      }, "text");
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK

```
$.post("SomePage.aspx", { name : "value" },
          function (data) {
             window.open("http://www.google.com");
          }, "text");
```

In the first example, I get alerted with what i'm expecting.  In the second example, nothing happens.  No window is opened.  If I add an alert or something before or after the window.open call, the alert works fine, but the window doesn't open.  If I add a window.open completly after the $.post method, the window opens fine (of course this doens't help me at all).

I'm wondering why I can't open a window in the callback.  What do I have to do to be able to open a window?  I'd like to open a window to show some fancy results.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're fighting a popup blocker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should work?

try it with the name of the window?

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "MyWindow");
```

according to this post

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

> The syntax of the window.open method
>   is given below: open (URL,
>   windowName[, windowFeatures])

the 2nd parameter is not optional (of course, everything is optional in javascript), maybe something weird happens in the callback without it?

also, possible it is opening in a new tab or behind the current window?

```
var x = window.open("http://www.google.com", "MyWindow");
x.focus();
```

Comment: He's being stopped by a popup blocker.

Comment: it seems to at least tell me that in IE, Chrome it just silently does nothing, thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

This is my sample solution:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    . . .
    url: "MyService.aspx/ConstructUrl",
    success: function(url) {
        window.open(url); 
})
```

added additional ajax option "async:false" and it caused openning URL in a new Tab. It works well in chrome and firefox.