# How to open a new browser tab from within a jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have tried the following to achieve this:

- [Jquery Open in new Tab (_blank)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950269/jquery-open-in-new-tab-blank)
- [How can I open a link in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827637/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-a-new-window)

But neither works when calling `window.open` from inside the callback. Here's my code

```
$.post('api', { 
    }, function() {
    var win = window.open('target-file', '_blank');
    win.focus();
    });
```

Comment: The new window may be blocked by a popup-blocker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I open a new window on my jquery ajax callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791047/why-cant-i-open-a-new-window-on-my-jquery-ajax-callback)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $.post('api', { 
    }, function() {
    window.open('target-file', '_blank');
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

try it with the name of the window

Like

```
window.open("url", "NameOfNewWindow");
```

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791047/why-cant-i-open-a-new-window-on-my-jquery-ajax-callback)

Answer (score 0):

use    `MySurfaceWindow = window.open("url","windowname","settings");`
see below example:

```
MySurfaceWindow = window.open('/DesktopModules/DMS/DMS.PatientEChart/Surface Pages/Surface6.aspx?SurfaceTooth=' + $("#lbl" + $(this).val()).text() + '&ProcedureID=0' + '&ColorD=I' + '', '', 'height=240,width=200,top=' + top + ',left=' + left + 'status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
```

Answer (score 0):

ou can add this simple jQuery snipplet to your source to open every external link in a new tab of the web browser

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
    if(!a.test(this.href)) {
      $(this).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
      });
    }
  });
});
```